# Determine if a function is bijective

Tags: functions

If a function is injective and has the same domain and codomain, say $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R $, am I correct in thinking that it has to also be surjective?

Comment: This is true for finite sets, but not for infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $f(x,y)=(e^x,e^y)$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the same size? I mean, cardinality
If yes it's true for finite sets to finite sets
But it's not true for infinite sets

Comment: what exactly do you mean by same size? OP hasn't mentioned cardinality anywhere...